# sqlcmd goto isn't quite working—ends script on error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I am using the sqlcmd tool with SQL Server to execute scripts.  The scripts add/update records.  I need sqlcmd to stop executing and give a non 0 return value if the script throws an error.  I thought the following would work but it does not.

```
    DECLARE @intErrorCode INT
BEGIN TRAN T1;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTable ON 

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(some_type_id,some_type,code_definition,use_some_lookup,created_by,created_on,modified_by,modified_on,org_some)
VALUES(0,'yadayada','None','N','system',GETDATE(),'system',GETDATE(),'N')

 SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTable OFF


UPDATE dbo.SomeTable 
SET some_type = 'Contract Analytical'
WHERE some_type_id = 2

 SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM



PROBLEM:
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) BEGIN
PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SELECT @intErrorCode
    RETURN
END
COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you start sqlcmd with the [`-b` on error batch abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) option to stop on error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-zero return value you can return the value in @intErrorCode

ala

```
RETURN @intErrorCode
```

Selecting it returns it in a result set rather than return value.

Answer (score 0):

try using try-catch:

```
DECLARE @intErrorCode INT
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN T1;

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTable ON 

    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (some_type_id,some_type,code_definition,use_some_lookup,created_by,created_on,modified_by,modified_on,org_some)
        VALUES(0,'yadayada','None','N','system',GETDATE(),'system',GETDATE(),'N')

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTable OFF


    UPDATE dbo.SomeTable 
        SET some_type = 'Contract Analytical'
        WHERE some_type_id = 2

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF XACT_STATE()!=0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    SELECT
        ,ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber --same as @@ERROR
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    RETURN 999

END CATCH
COMMIT TRAN T1;
RETURN 0
```